# Don't change Custom Post Type slug to unique value

Tags: customization, slug, permalinks

I have a situation where it is needed that if I create two CPT pages wich both have the same name and the same slug.

For example, if I add two CPT pages, wich both called *"Post Name"*:
The first slug will be *"post-name"*,
The second slug will be *"post-name-2"*.

Because I added a custom part to the permalink structure wich will make the URL unique:

```
function extra_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    if ( stripos( $permalink, '%selected_meta%' ) == false )
        return $permalink;

    if ( is_object( $post ) && ($post->post_type == 'ervaring' || $post->post_type == 'lening') ) {
        $_selected_post_slug = '';
        $_selected_post_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rating-post', true );

        if ( $_selected_post_id )
            $_selected_post_slug = get_page_uri( $_selected_post_id );

        return str_replace( '%selected_meta%', $_selected_post_slug, $permalink );
    }

    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'extra_post_link', 10, 3 );
```

How do I prevent WordPress from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might consider the 'wp_unique_post_slug' filter:

```
   add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug','my_disable_unique_slug',11,6);
    function disable_unique_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ){
        global $post;       
        if($post->post_type=='cpt'){ // EDIT post type
            $slug=$original_slug;
        }
        return $slug;
    }
```

This is untested, but you get the idea ;-)

ps: you might have to change other things to make this work, since the unique-ness is so important.

Comment: Oh thank you very much! I sure have to change some other things in order to receive the correct post when the item is viewed. But since that wasn't exactly the question, I consider this one answered. :-)